# Is there a better way of implementing this without multiple fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, fetch-api

This is login component from a react application and I am trying to do a simple authentication login with Firebase as my real time database.

My first approach is to execute a fetch request (GET) to see if there is any existing user. Afterwhich, if the password do match with the user, I want to update the "isLoggedIn" field to true. In order to achieve the following, another fetch request (PATCH) was made.

Therefore, I am wondering if it is a bad practice to have multiple fetch request in one function and would like to know if there is a more efficient or better way of implementing this simple application?

```
 const loginHandler = async (userName, password) => {
    const url = `insert_url_link_here/users/${userName}.json`;
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const user = await response.json();
      if (user.password === password) {
        await fetch(url, {
          method: "PATCH",
          body: JSON.stringify({ isLoggedIn: true }),
        });

      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

This is the schema of my database.

```
--users:
    eric:
        isLoggedIn: false
        password: "321"

    test:
        isLoggedIn: false
        password: "222"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing the Firebase Realtime Database through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start), which implements simple CRUD operations, and there's no way to combine a read and a write operation into a single operation there.

The only other relevant operation is the [conditional write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-conditional-requests), which you can use to only write data if it hasn't been modified since you read it. You can use this to implement an optimistic compare-and-set like transaction mechanism, but given that you're toggling a boolean it doesn't seem to apply here.

---

If you're on an environment that supports it, you may want to consider using the Firebase SDK for that platform, as the SDKs typically use a web socket to communicate with the server, which often ends up being a lot more efficient than performing multiple individual HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Firebase client implementation and looking at the Firebase documentation. There are well described and explicit examples in various languages:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Besides, I don't see the point of storing passwords or login state on your side since Firebase Auth already does this for you in a secure way.